# Obtener de una imagen el último dato de un gráfico de líneas

Tags: python

necesito de su ayuda.
Quiero obtener los datos de una imagen que contiene un gráfico y líneas de tendencia. Hay alguna manera de hacer esto en python?

Si es así que librería se podría usar quedó atento a sus comentarios
Les dejo el gráfico del cuál necesito obtener los datos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Se que para ver los datos de una imagen pixel a pixel existe la libreria Pillow pero no se si sera lo que buscas

Comment: ¿Que has intentado para resolver el problema?

Comment: @hlecuanda cómo puedo internar algo si estoy comenzando a buscar información?

Comment: Para ayudar con este tipo de preguntas se espera que quien pregunta demuestre haber intentado resolver el problema ([help/on-topic]) o bien, mencionar la investigación previa o alguna dificultad específica con la solución. Hay más información en [ask].